# an int data plus $('input').val(),the result is a string?! not a number

Tags: string, input, numbers

I have a simple input control :

```
<input type="text" min="0" max="100" value="0">
```

then I do a sum compute:

```
 var a=10;
 console.log(a+$('input').val());
```

however the result is '100',not '10'?!

why ?how can I get the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$('input').val()` is a string, so `a` is converted to a string, and the `+` concatenates them.  Try:

```
a + Number($('input').val())
```

This will convert the value of the textbox to a number, allowing the `+` to be the addition operator.

Comment: try `Number()`... case matters in js.